# SPSS: Is there a way to save table-output of SPSS as a sav file?

Tags: dataset, spss

How can I export SPSS output e.g an estimate table as a .sav file?

I tried to do it over the menu-> utilities -> OMS Control Panel but couldn't find it.

Comment: OMS is the solution - maybe we can help if you give more details about what you were looking for and what went wrong.

Comment: Thx. I need to save my parameter-estimates-table in SPSS output  as a sav-file. Not trough OMS but hopefully through a  syntax code.

Comment: I have an example of using OMS for regression [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20661781/604456). As JKP says though as well, you can use the OUTFILE subcommand at can save both the parameter covariances as well as the estimates.

Comment: Thx but I didnt undrestand your code.

Answer (score 2):

OMS is syntax.  You write an OMS command to acquire the particular table type  you want; then run the command or commands; then run OMSEND.  Also, if you are using the REGRESSION command, the OUTFILE subcommand can save regression results as well.